# Swift: Benefits of Curry Function

Tags: swift, currying

I'm trying to grasp the concept behind curry functions.   Below is the code:

```
class MyHelloWorldClass {

    func helloWithName(name: String) -> String {
        return "hello, \(name)"
    }
}
```

I can create a variable that points to the class’s `helloWithName` function:

```
let helloWithNameFunc = MyHelloWorldClass.helloWithName
// MyHelloWorldClass -> (String) -> String
```

My new `helloWithNameFunc` is of type `MyHelloWorldClass -> (String) -> String`, a `function` that takes in an instance of my `class` and `returns` another `function` that takes in a `string` value and returns a `string` value.

So I can actually call my `function` like this:

```
let myHelloWorldClassInstance = MyHelloWorldClass()

helloWithNameFunc(myHelloWorldClassInstance)("Mr. Roboto") 
// hello, Mr. Roboto
```

Credit: I go this code from this [site](http://www.objc.io/issue-16/swift-functions.html)

What is the benefit of using the above curry function?  When would there a need to call a function that takes an instance of its class, that takes the subsequent parameter that was passed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is 'Currying'?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314/what-is-currying)

Comment: You accepted an answer that doesn't really illustrate currying but instead partial evaluation.  And it didn't even use the builtin Swift curry syntax.  Okay, up to you.

Comment: Well, my question was marked as a duplicate.  I didn't think I would have an answer so I marked it as correct.  I unaccepted it.  Please feel free to answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the example given isn't an example of currying exactly. That's why you don't see any value in it.

This is a better example of currying:

```
class MyHelloWorldClass {
    //Function that takes two arguments
    func concatenateStrings(string1: String, string2: String) {
        return "\(string1)\(string2)"
    }
    //Curried version of concatenateStrings that takes one argument. 
    func helloWithName(name: String) -> String {
        return concatenateStrings("hello, ", name)
    }
}
```

This is a better example of how function variables are curried functions in Swift: http://oleb.net/blog/2014/07/swift-instance-methods-curried-functions/